# WPF C# game: code delay method that delays a line

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a small game project were you can shoot, but the main problem is that there is no delay between shots so I tried using different timers. The one that seemed to be the best option was dispatcherTime but when it ran it stopped the whole program for 5 seconds so I just want to know if there is a way to delay a line of code in the program without stopping everything or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Don't code delay statements, that will block your thread and disable your user from doing anything. I would use a timer and public boolean flag that is set TRUE, when the timer should do the shooting. In the timer you can set the flag back to FALSE when you decide to shoot. On this tick.. or on the next tick.. or after 10 ticks.. depending how fast the user can shoot.

Comment: totally bizarre reason to close this question how can this be considered a opinion related question? just because there could be different solutions to a problem doesn’t make it opinion based, hack any question related to LINQ could be Closed stating opinion because one someone has the opinion to write it with a for loop, the other prefers for each, the next a while loop, the one after this prefers do loop, one would prefer a switch over an if and so on...

Comment: @RandRandom, There is no point reopening if it can fall under a close reason. 
A quick search engine query show while there are a lot of question about WPF and Delay action they often not the one OP is ascking for. 
So we are left with focus, and clarity. You can try to edit the question Title and Body to salvage it. 

And you will have an issue Op is talking about an issue with "_dispatcherTime but when it ran it stopped the whole program for 5 seconds_" but there is no MRE.

Comment: This is my first post on here so I have no idea why this has been flagged for something but I am taking your comments into account so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void ShootBox_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
    {
        if (_cancellationTokenSource != null)
            return;

        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        await ShootThatDamnPistol(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
    private void ShootBox_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        _cancellationTokenSource = null;
    }
    async Task ShootThatDamnPistol(CancellationToken cToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!cToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(500, cToken);
                ShootBox.Text += "Bang!" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            //nope
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp17.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBox x:Name="ShootBox"
             KeyDown="ShootBox_OnKeyDown"
             KeyUp="ShootBox_OnKeyUp" />
</Window>
```

Comment: .... that is better than my comment.